# A subspace topology of a subspace topology.

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $X$ is a topological space and let $A$ and $B$ be subspaces of $X$ such that $A\subset B\subset X$.
(Should I be more precise? i.e. should I state like "$B$ is a subspace of $X$ and $A$ is a subspace of $B$"?)
I'm thinking about a statement "$A$ has the discrete topology." It is equivalent to saying that for each $a\in A$, $\{a\}$ is open in $A$.

But what is the meaning of '$\{a\}$ being open in $A$?'

1. There exists $U$, open in $B$ such that $\{a\}=U\cap A$.
2. There exists $V$, open in $X$ such that $\{a\}=V\cap A$.

Are they equivalent to each other?

I think they are equivalent.
($\Downarrow$) is trivial since $U$ is open in $X$.
($\Uparrow$) : $B\cap V$ is an open set in $B$ and $V\cap A=(B\cap V)\cap A$.

Am I right?

Comment: They are equivalent because the Topology induced by B on A is equivalent to the Topology induced by X on A

Comment: @FedericoFallucca I see, I didn't know that, although this is such an elementary one.

Comment: Your $U$ in the last line is open in $B$, not open in $X$.

Answer (score 1):

They are equivalent. Either one knows that the subspace topology that $A$ has with respect to $B$ is the same as it has with respect to $X$. Or we just see that if $\{a\}=U \cap A$ with $U$ open in $B$, so $U=O \cap B$ for some open $O$ in $X$ and so $$\{a\} = U \cap A= (O \cap B) \cap A = O \cap (B \cap A) = O \cap A$$ using $A \cap B= A$ as $A \subseteq B$. And if $O$ is open in $X$ with $O \cap A=\{a\}$ then we could also have taken $V=B \cap O$ as an open set of $B$ having the same intersection with $A$, etc.